# Regex to remove whitespace and parenthesis?

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm trying to remove the following: `"    (23wr)"`

To remove the white spaces I have used `.gsub(/\s+/, "")`, but how can I remove the `'('` and `')'` to get `"23wr"` ?

Comment: Do you want to remove this exact string?

Comment: Or another, always has the same syntax

Comment: Maybe, line.gsub!(/\s?\((\w+)\)/, "#{$1}")?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this code:

```
gsub(/[\s+)(]/,"")
```

Comment: Why using + inside a character class?

Comment: I agree, you can leave the + off.

Answer (score 1):

No regex:

```
p " (23wr)".delete("( )\t") #=> "23wr"
```

Comment: How will this react to `"hello\tworld"`?

Comment: It would ignore the tab. Adding \t to the ignore string works (post edited).

Comment: How will this react to `"hello" + x + "world"`, where `x` represents an arbitrary Unicode whitespace character? Yes, yes, I'm being pedantic. The point is, coding for the particular can often ignore the general.